# ¿Se deshabilitan las licencias al instalar Upgrade 12 de Genexus 15?

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Quiero instalar el Upgrade 12 de Genexus 15. Actualmente tenemos instalado genexus con upgrade 7 y nuestras licencias las tenemos instaladas en un servidor con protection service 9.6.4.40.

Cuando quise instalar el upgrade 12 en el licence manager habilita un botón "Upgrade Legacy". Mi pregunta: ¿no se deshabilitan las licencias al realizar este proceso?

Answer (score 0):

No se deshabilitan las licencias.
Es decir, el proceso lo que hace es actualizar las licencias pero como son "backward compatibles" (podés usar upgrades o versiones anteriores) no hay problema.
Si el server donde están las licencias tiene salida a internet, lo más práctico es hacerlo online.

Más información: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37140,GeneXus+15+Upgrade+8+Protection+Changes